# Read a file places in same dir as class?

Tags: java, file-io

```
reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
```

The file is placed in the same directory as the java class. Anyhow I get FileNotFoundException.

What is wrong?

Comment: you can get the current dir with new File(".").getAbsolutPath() for debugging purposes...

Comment: or more  simply System.getProperty("user.dir")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory. In your code sample, if `file.txt` isn't in your current directory, it won't be found.

Be wary of using relative paths in your code. That's because it's impossible to tell at compile time what the current working directory will be when your code is run.

If the file is part of your deployment, store it on the classpath and access it via `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()`, if it's truly external data that the user can change, put the file name in a configuration of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

File needs to be in the root folder of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your application doesn't run in that directory. You would either have to use an absolute (or classpath-relative) path, or move the file to the directory where the application runs. In Eclipse, for example, this would be the root folder of your project.